# Android Navigation Drawer App not reacting on a click

Tags: android

I have a Problem, I made a Android Navigation Drawer App and added my stuff.

Now I have a Problem and I don't know where the bug could be:

When I want to see the Navigation Drawer, I only can use the swipe gesture from the left device border.

When I click at the top left corner [image] to show the menu it does not work.

Any tips for a solution?

Comment: Where is the code for the listener on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html), tying it to your `Activity` and `DrawerLayout`.  Note that you'll also need to call `ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` in order for your `onOptionsItemSelected()` callback to see the `android.R.id.home` as being selected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a click listener for the button and then you will have the ability to open and close the drawer: this can be done in the Activity after onCreate() is called.

```
viewButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.actionBarViewButton);
    viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }

            else{
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
    });
```